# Javascript: Copy to clipboard in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, clipboard

I'm well aware that iOS Safari doesn't support document.execCommand("copy"). However, I would like to make it as easy as possible for iOS users to copy a block of text.

[image]

A user can long-press a word on the page, which will highlight the word. They can then manipulate the selection range to highlight the entire text block, but this can be a bit touchy. Once they have the entire range selected, they get a callout balloon with various options, including copy. I'd like to find a way to simplify this workflow if at all possible.

It's possible to create a button to highlight text for a user with one click. But this doesn't bring up the text options bubble. And when the user long-presses that selection, it reselects just a single word.

Is it possible to highlight an entire text block (with the options bubble) on long press? Are there other ways to make the copy/paste easier for users?